# Sort pandas dataframe rows according to a string value column

Tags: python, string, pandas, sorting, rows

I have the following dataframe :

```
        month       price
0       April  102.478015
1      August   94.868053
2    December   97.278205
3    February  100.114510
4     January   99.419109
5        July   93.402928
6        June   96.114224
7       March  101.297762
8         May  102.905340
9    November   97.952169
10    October   95.606478
11  September   94.226803
```

I would like to have the months in a coherent order (January in the first row until December in the 12th row). How please could I do ?

If necessary, you can copy this dataframe and then execute

```
pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')
```

to have the dataframe on your jupyter notebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert values to ordered `categorical`s, so possible use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
cats = ['January','February','March','April','May','June',
        'July','August','September','October','November','December']
df['month'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['month'], ordered=True, categories=cats)
#alternative
#df['month'] = pd.Categorical(df['month'], ordered=True, categories=cats)
df = df.sort_values('month')
print (df)
        month       price
4     January   99.419109
3    February  100.114510
7       March  101.297762
0       April  102.478015
8         May  102.905340
6        June   96.114224
5        July   93.402928
1      August   94.868053
11  September   94.226803
10    October   95.606478
9    November   97.952169
2    December   97.278205
```

Comment: and you can use `calendar.month_name` to generate `cats` variable

Comment: Why `pd.CategoricalIndex` instead of `pd.Categorical` @jez?

Comment: @yatu - Because in some oldier pandas version `Categorical` failed, only working `CategoricalIndex`